# Active record get all instance that do not match condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, querying

I have the following AR query which returns an array of rooms (the rooms that are not available in the time period given) :

```
rooms = Room.joins(:bookings).where("(bookings.start_date >= ? AND bookings.start_date <= ?) OR (bookings.end_date >= ? AND bookings.end_date <= ?) OR (bookings.start_date <= ? AND bookings.end_date >= ?)", from, to, from, to, from, to)
```

I want to modify that query so it returns all the other rooms; that is the ones that are available in the requested time period. The right result is givent by the following :

```
all_rooms = Room.all
available_rooms = all_rooms - rooms
```

But I directly want to get the available rooms in a single query. I already added a .not but it doesnt give me the right result :

```
rooms = Room.joins(:bookings).where.not("(bookings.start_date >= ? AND bookings.start_date <= ?) OR (bookings.end_date >= ? AND bookings.end_date <= ?) OR (bookings.start_date <= ? AND bookings.end_date >= ?)", from, to, from, to, from, to)
```

How should I modify the query ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say:

```
A = (bookings.start_date >= ? AND bookings.start_date <= ?)
B = (bookings.end_date >= ? AND bookings.end_date <= ?) 
C = (bookings.start_date <= ? AND bookings.end_date >= ?)
first_logic  = A or B or C
second_logic = not(first_logic) = not(A or B or C) = not(A) and not(B) and not(C)
```

`available_rooms` is the condition of `second_logic`, so it will be like:

```
available_rooms = Room.joins(:bookings)
                      .where.not("bookings.start_date >= ? AND bookings.start_date <= ?", from, to)
                      .where.not("bookings.end_date >= ? AND bookings.end_date <= ?", from, to)
                      .where.not("bookings.start_date <= ? AND bookings.end_date >= ?", from, to)
```